# Javascript - Permutation and Possibility

Tags: javascript, permutation

Hi i'm looking to generate all possibilitys of a set of characters with Javascript. The code i have so far generates this array from the character set 'abc' and length of 3:

`["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]`

But what i'm looking to generate is every possibility from the character set 'abc' max length of 3. a-ccc :

`["a", "b", "c", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb", "bc", "ca", "cb", "cc", "aaa", "aab", "aac", "aba", "abb", "abc"...."ccc"]`

Here is the the code i'm using to generate the first array, any help would be appreciated.

```
var permutate = (function() {
    var results = [];
    function doPermute(input, output, used, size, level) {
        if (size == level) {
            var word = output.join('');
            results.push(word);
            return;
        }
        level++;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (used[i] === true) {
                continue;
            }
            used[i] = true;
            output.push(input[i]);
            doPermute(input, output, used, size, level);
            used[i] = false;
            output.pop();
        }
    }
    return {
        getPermutations: function(input, size) {
            var chars = input.split('');
            var output = [];
            var used = new Array(chars.length);
            doPermute(chars, output, used, size, 0);
            return results;
        }
    }
})();
function test(letters, size) {
    var testResults = permutate.getPermutations(letters, size);
    console.log(testResults);
};
test('abc', 3)
```

Comment: This answer might be a good start; http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59615/recursive-function-that-generates-the-permutations-of-a-string

Comment: The output you want has nothing to do with permutations. You want all [words of length <=3 over the alphabet `abc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language#Words_over_an_alphabet) (which has a completely different, albeit quite trivial algorithm to construct)

Comment: Try yourself: Think of an algorithm that can give you all words of length `3` when given all words of length `2`. Then put that in a recursion (base case is the empty word `""`) and concat the results of each length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :)

```
function allPermutations(letters,maxSize){
  function permutations(letters,size){
    var results=[];
    for(var i=0;i<letters.length;i++){
      var res=letters[i];
      if(size===1){
        results.push(res);
      }else{
        var rest=permutations(letters,size-1);
        for(var j=0;j<rest.length;j++){
          results.push(res+rest[j]);
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  };
  var results=[];
  for(var i=1;i<=maxSize;i++){
    results=results.concat(permutations(letters,i));
  }
  return results;
}
console.log(allPermutations('abc',3));
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ECHDK

Comment: Your `permutations` function doesn't seem to work with a `size` of `0`

Comment: it does work. it returns an empty array... and since the sample desired output provided by the OP does not include the empty string, then empty array is the correct output for size 0.

Comment: quoting the op:
But what i'm looking to generate is every possibility from the character set 'abc' max length of 3. a-ccc :

["a", "b", "c", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb", "bc", "ca", "cb", "cc", "aaa", "aab", "aac", "aba", "abb", "abc"...."ccc"]

Comment: I don't mean your `allPermutations` function, but the `permutations` one - when I pass `0` then I get a stack overflow. I wanted to suggest to use `0` as the base case, not `1`.

Comment: oh, ok... i did not meant that function to be used directly, but you are right, it should be foolproofed... like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lJivn for instance

Comment: Yes - or you just change the base case of the recursion :-) [edit] your answer (in either way) and you'll get an upvote!

Comment: ok, edited my answer to include the change that foolproofs my solution, as sugested by @Bergi

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like counting in base 4 is the way to go.  The trick here is to remember that nothing, `''`, is also an option (equivalent to `0` in arithmetic).  So you have to include that in your array of options.  You could achieve this with three nested loops:

```
options = ['','a','b','c'];
output = [];
for ( var x = 0; x < options.length; x++ )
    for ( var y = 0; y < options.length; y++ )
        for ( var z = 0; z < options.length; z++ )
            output.push(options[x]+options[y]+options[z]);
```

You're nesting three loops because the maximum length of the output will be 3 (remember that concatenating `''` doesn't increase length.

You could also achieve this using recursion.  This way you would only have to write one for-loop.  I'll leave that part to you, good luck!

Comment: Um, no. `''` is not a digit, and we're not counting in base 4. If you check deliberately, your output does contain duplicates.

Comment: OP did not ask for non-duplicates.

Comment: I think that's quite clear from his requested example that he would like them lexicographically ordered and without duplicates.

Comment: Then perhaps you'd be making a greater contribution to the community by correcting the example with the one-liner that would fix this problem.

Comment: Well, `function words(alphabet, n) { return n==0 ? [""] : (function(next) { return alphabet.reduce(function(p, chr) { return p.concat(next.map(function(n) { return chr+n; }));}, next); }(words(alphabet, n-1))); }` would probably do if you're looking for a one-liner, but I guess the OP is not.

Comment: This is not a 'fix', it's a new solution. A new solution that still contains duplicates.

Comment: You're right, I went down the wrong path. The actual duplicate-free solution is much easier: `function words(alphabet, n) { return n==0 ? [""] : words(alphabet, n-1).reduce(function(p, n) { return p.concat(alphabet.map(function(chr) { return n+chr; }));}, [""]); }`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix your nested loops, so I tried to develop a one-liner…